# Transfer ETH from wallet into two different accounts(sites)

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

Could I have one wallet that can be used for two different cryptocurrency sites?
For example: If I transfer ETH into my wallet form one site, could I used my ETH in my wallet to deposit the ETH into another trading site?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Yes, my friend, you can transfer the ETH from the exchange to a physical wallet then from that physical wallet you can transfer the ETH to any exchange site which you desire .. remember this is a two-way process alternatively what you can do is just withdraw your ETH from one site directly to the Exchange wallet in this way you can save your transaction fees and time too!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have personal control over your wallet (for example, you're using MyEtherWallet, MetaMask, Mist or Parity) you can send your ETH to any address you want. This includes the deposit addresses of your trading site accounts.